# BeautifulSoup find_all with arguments

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my first experience with BeautifulSoup  and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong

```
<table class="table sortable table-striped table-condensed r-tab-enabled">
 <thead>
    <tr class="r-tab-buttons r-only-tablet">
       <th class="r-tab-button active" data-defaultsort="disabled" data-group="1">Picks</th>
       <th class="r-tab-button" data-defaultsort="disabled" data-group="2">Bans</th>
       <th class="r-tab-button" data-defaultsort="disabled" data-group="3">Combined</th>
    </tr>
```

This is a sample of HTML page I'm working with and my code:

```
r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_attr('class') and tag['class'] =="table sortable table-striped table-condensed r-tab-enabled")
```

it returns nothing, but this works

```
table = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_attr('class'))
```

So should it return nothing? Or how do I input arguments into `find_all`

Comment: You only need to use `lambdas` when you need to do something outside what the existing arguments take. Looks like you're after `soup.find_all('table', class_='table')` (replacing that with classes you're interested in). Or, you could use CSS selectors which are generally more readable... `soup.select('table.table')` ... Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your sample code is comparing `tag['class']` with a string value `"table sortable table-striped table-condensed r-tab-enabled"` while `tag['class']` is an array.

To fix your code, compare `tag['class']` with an array

```
table = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='table' and tag.has_attr('class') and tag['class'] == ["table", "sortable", "table-striped", "table-condensed", "r-tab-enabled"])
```

Or as @Jon point out in the comment, use selector instead

```
table = soup.select('table.table.sortable.table-striped.table-condensed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you going through this process, you can only use `find_all('table', class_='classes string')` and you get all tables from html file

```
text = """
    <table class="table sortable table-striped table-condensed r-tab-enabled">
 <thead>
    <tr class="r-tab-buttons r-only-tablet">
       <th class="r-tab-button active" data-defaultsort="disabled" data-group="1">Picks</th>
       <th class="r-tab-button" data-defaultsort="disabled" data-group="2">Bans</th>
       <th class="r-tab-button" data-defaultsort="disabled" data-group="3">Combined</th>
    </tr>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('table', class_="table sortable table-striped table-condensed r-tab-enabled"):
    print(i)
```

And you got your information, May be this help!